# jquery selector with specific class and data attribute

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a litte problem with selecting a table row with specific class and a specific data attribute.

I hope anyone has an idea.

This is the HTML source

```
    <table id="source" class="connectedSource" width="100%">
    <thead>
    ...
    <tbody>
    ...
    <tr class="headrow" bgcolor="#c2c2c2">
    ...
    <tr data-obj_id="904" class="datarow ui-draggable" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    ...
    <tr data-obj_id="906" class="datarow ui-draggable" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    ...
    <tr data-obj_id="908" class="datarow ui-draggable" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    ...
    <tr data-obj_id="903" class="datarow ui-draggable" bgcolor="#efefef">
    ...
```

This works fine ...

```
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('selector = ' + "tbody tr.datarow");
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('source row class = ' + $("#source").find("tbody tr.datarow").attr('class'));
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('source row obj_id = ' + $("#source").find("tbody tr.datarow").data('obj_id'));
```

The result ...

```
    selector = tbody tr.datarow
    source row class = datarow ui-draggable
    source row obj_id = 904
```

This doesn't work ...

```
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('selector = ' + "tbody tr.datarow[data-obj_id='" + source_obj_id + "']");
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('source row class = ' + $("#source").find("tbody tr.datarow[data-obj_id='" + source_obj_id + "']").attr('class'));
    if ($.browser.mozilla) console.log('source row obj_id = ' + $("#source").find("tbody tr.datarow[data-obj_id='" + source_obj_id + "']").data('obj_id'));
```

The result ...

```
    selector = tbody tr.datarow[data-obj_id='875']
    source row class = undefined
    source row obj_id = undefined
```

I have to select the datarow with data-obj_id = 908

I hope anyone can help ...

Thanx

Talki

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sGhKs/1/

Answer (score 3):

since your obj_id is unique.. i don't think you need class selector there

try with

```
 "tbody tr[data-obj_id='" + source_obj_id + "']"
```

Comment: The Result = selector = tbody tr[data-obj_id='908']
source row class = undefined
source row obj_id = undefined

Comment: make sure your `source_obj_id` is correct... working example http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/MgZFA/

Comment: oh my goodness ...

i found my problem ...

ther are 2 tables (source and destination) ... it works with drag and drop ...

if object is dropped on destination table, the object in source was removed ... that was the only problem ...

thanx for help ...

Talki